# Libgdx texturepacker doesn't pack all images

Tags: libgdx, texturepacker

When i run the texturepacker in libgdx i have the problem that it doesn't pack all the images in one big sprite sheet. If i for example have 4 images and it only packs 3 of them. Note that 2 images are the exact copies of eachother so maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: I curious - why do you need 2 exactly the same images?

Comment: I repeat a frame in a walk cycle animation. Unless i'm doing something wrong, i'm new to animation. So yeah maybe its not necessary to use exact copies of images.

Comment: There must be a way to re-use image. I'm animating object on my own, but no matter what way you are creating animations there must be some solution to avoid double images...

Comment: Yeah, actually you can just leave it alone. Aliasing is on by default in TexturePacker. It will still give you all your frames of animation when you load it in the game. There will be separate TextureRegions referring to the same region of the atlas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LibGDX by default doesn't pack images which are exact copies. This can be overridden by setting `alias` to `false` in your configuration.

> **alias:** If true, two images that are pixel for pixel the same will only be packed once. (default: true)

However, usually it is beneficial to pack the same images only once because it creates a smaller texture. You can still use both names when getting `TextureRegion` objects or creating `Sprite`.

Comment: Do you mean with configuration the atlas file that is generated? I have tried to put (alias: true) inside that but it gives an error. So i'm not shure where the configuration is located.

Comment: Nevermind figured it out. Yust used a Settings class and asigned alias to false and asigned that to the TexturePacker.process()

Comment: Yeah, you need to use `Settings` class or `pack.json` created in the directory with images to pack.

Answer (score 2):

Set `alias` to false in the texture packer settings.

[Documentation here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer#settings)